# How do I share liked statuses & liked comments from my Facebook Activity log either privately or public?

Tags: facebook

I would like to make available to my non-Facebook friends (and sometimes Facebook ones, too, who miss my activity in news ticker) all the posts or comments that I like on Facebook.

I know using Graph API I can read pages I like, but I could not find posts and comments I liked because it shows just pages and not individual posts.

How do I do get instead the list of all posts and comments I've liked?